# Mapping properties from a foreign table twice in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent

I have 2 tables like this: (Please note the non-standard db schema naming)

```
table T_Pen
  TP_ID
  TP_PrimaryColorID
  TP_SecondaryColorID
  ...

table E_Color
  EC_ID
  EC_ColorName
  ...
```

And I want to create a mapping of the 2 tables to a domain object `Pen` using Fluent NHibernate.

```
class Pen
{
    PenID;
    PrimaryColorName;
    SecondaryColorName;
    ...
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you would be able to Insert/Update anymore if you were to only reference the Name.

You could create a view of PenColour or hide the actual reference in your pen class and only expose the Name property.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Basically, another class (e.g. PenColor) is needed acting as a view for read-only purpose, and in order by have update and insert possible, the Pen object still need to refer to Color objects, (which is not too bad, but that's kind of an abstraction leak), right?

Comment: One question: when you say a "view" of PenColor, do you mean a database view, or a class?

Answer (score 0):

class Pen 
{
    int PenID;
    Color PrimaryColor;
    Color SecondaryColor;
}

class Color
{
    int ColorID;
    string ColorName;

}

class ColorMap
{
    Id(x => x.ColorID);
    Map(x => x.ColorName);
}

class PenMap
{
    Id(x => x.PenID);
    References(x => x.PrimaryColor).Column("TP_PrimaryColorID");
    References(x => x.SecondaryColor).Column("TP_SecondaryColorID");
}

Comment: I don't want to reference a Color object in a Pen object, just the name of the colors, can this be done?

Comment: yes, you can create a view which contains two varchar columns PrimaryColorName and SecondaryColorName. The limitation is that you won't be able to update or insert.

Comment: Thanks! I think user456813 gave the same answer.

Comment: @tonyjy: What if Color was unique to a given Pen and you wanted to map back a Pen property from Color object ? I can't find any solution to this pbm...